# What does the error "'ClassName -> () -> ClassName' does not have a member named 'memberName'" mean?

Tags: swift

I want to write a class with 2 computed properties, where the second one references the first. I tried this:

```
class GraphView: UIView {
    var graphVisibleSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(
            width:  self.bounds.size.width  / 40,
            height: self.bounds.size.height / 40)
    }
    var graphRect = CGRect {
        return CGRect(
            center: CGPointZero,
            size: self.graphVisibleSize)
    }
}
```

However, that results in an error. Xcode gives an error on the `size: self.graphVisibleSize` line and says:

```
'GraphView -> () -> GraphView' does not have a member named 'graphVisibleSize'
```

What does this mean? Specifically:

1. What does the `GraphView -> () -> GraphView` part mean?
2. Why can it not see the `graphVisibleSize` member that is right above it?
3. Bonus question: I tried to replicate this in a test class and ended up writing a class that works just fine - but I don't understand what's different! Here's the one I wrote just as a test:

   ```
   func mungeString(str: String) -> String {
       var newString = "--asdf--\(str)--qwer--"
       return newString
   }

   class TestClass: UIView {
       var baseA: String = "This is a string"
       var baseB: String {
           return "This is a computed string"
       }
       var changedA: String {
           return self.baseA.lowercaseString
       }
       var changedB: String {
           return mungeString(self.baseB)
       }
   }
   ```

   Why does this code work just fine, but the original code give me an error?

Comment: `self` is not the GraphView. notice how `baseA` is refered to directly in the second example.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I was trying things out before posting and didn't fix that. I've changed my test class now to look for `self.baseA` and `self.baseB`.

Comment: Also, when I *remove* `self.` from the line in the `GraphView` class, so that it becomes `size: graphVisibleSize`, I get a different error: `'GraphView.Type' does not have a member named 'graphVisibleSize'`. It still can't find the member, and I'm still confused as to why

Comment: The direct initializer of an instance property cannot depend on another instance property because during initialization there is no instance yet. See the duplicate link. There are a _lot_ of other answers to this; please search before posting.

Comment: I don't think the dupe is my issue. I was able to fix it with David Skrundz' solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by this line

```
var graphRect = CGRect {
```

it should instead be

```
var graphRect: CGRect {
```

like the other `var`s

Comment: Ahhhhhhh I can't believe I missed that, thank you